# Unable to compare data in ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm unable to compare the `data` using an `if` statement. It always returns or alerts `verified`. I thought using `$.trim(data)` would solve the issue but it didn't. How do I tackle it please?

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#login").submit(function () {
        var data = {
            "action": "test"
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "../login.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data); //shows 0 or userid

                if ($.trim(data) !== "") {
                    alert("verified");
                    //$('.profile-popup-link').trigger('click');
                } else if ($.trim(data) == '0') {
                    alert("not verified");
                    //$('.invalid-popup-link').trigger('click');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats because `0 !== ""`  is true just invert `$.trim(data)=='0'`and `$.trim(data)!==""` in your if else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($.trim(data)!=="")
```

You say `data` is always either a userID or 0. Therefore this `if` condition will always be `true` - `data` is never just an empty string. I suggest you put `if($.trim(data)=='0')` as the first condition, return "not verified" if it is `true`, and on `else` do whatever you intended to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `0 !== ""` is true just invert `$.trim(data)=='0'` and `$.trim(data)!==""` in your if else. Don't forget,if else statements are executed from top to bottom and fall into the first match they find.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the jQuery $.trim function, just compare the returned value to 0.

Assuming data is either 0 or the id of the user, use the following success function:

```
        success: function (data) {
            if (data > 0) {
                alert("verified");
                //$('.profile-popup-link').trigger('click');
            } else {
                alert("not verified");
                //$('.invalid-popup-link').trigger('click');
            }
        }
```

As it works in my example: https://jsfiddle.net/0b28mt61/